# Google Plugin url for Eclipse (Juno) is not valid?

Tags: google-plugin-eclipse

I am trying to install the Google Plugin for Eclipse from this url

```
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2
```

and I get this error message

```
Communication with repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 failed.
Read timed out
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the firewall or virus protection is blocking the download of .jar files. In anycase the workaround for me was to do a local update of the site using the instructions from  here
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip

Make sure to check off the "Contact update site" in the "Install new software" dialog box or else it'll timeout again.